# Illustrator Scale Thickness Weight of Path Object for Icon Design

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, scale, outline

i have a `Compound Path` in Illustrator, that needs to be scaled in line thickness/weight without changing outer Bounds.

This Path was initially created by outlining a simple stroke. The Path consists of points and is closed

[image]

(only part of image is displayed here)

**There are also the hard requirements**:

- Number of points must be exactly equal from the original to scaled version
- The Layers and Elements hierarchy of scaled path must be exactly equal to original one.

How can this be done?

Trying to simply apply `Stroke` Weight results in a correct looking Version, but fails matching the requirements above when `Outline Stroke` is applied.
This adds a completely new set of points not only in position but also in point count:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Offset in by half tha size of stroke increase?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE, while offset will probably work, converting strokes to outlines is destructive. It would have been better to have kept a copy of the original stroked version. Then you could simply increase the stroke thickness before converting to outlines.

Comment: @BillyKerr
Yes this was exactly what i was doing.
I have the original stroke with thickness 0.
Increasing Thickness and Outlining creates the above points differently.

Answer (score 1):

As @joojaa mentions in the comment....

Remove the new stoke and choose `Object > Path > Offset` and enter a value *half* the size of the stroke you removed.